# PowerBi Calculated column not bringing over correct counts

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables. I want to add a calculated column that counts the amount of orders completed by month. The Year-Month column has been brought over through a summarize calculation so it's the same data that I'm trying to reference in the original table. Yet, the calculated column is only entered a number for items with no date.

[image]

This is the formula I used for my calculated column:

```
Column = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Renewed[Complete Count]),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Renewed[Year-Month]), Renewed[Year-Month] = SELECTEDVALUE(Closed[Year-Month]))
  )
```

I validated that both columns in the tables are formatted as below. What could be causing the issue of not populating?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECTEDVALUE` needs to be in a `CALCULATE` when in used in Calculated Columns, however you don't need `SELECTEDVALUE` in Calculated Columns.

Try:

```
Column = 
  var thisYM = [Year-Month]
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    SUM(Renewed[Complete Count]),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Renewed[Year-Month]), Renewed[Year-Month] = thisYM)
  )
```

You could also update your `Closed` table to include this from the get-go. Try:

```
Closed = SUMMARIZE(
    'Renewed',
    'Renewed'[Year-Month],
    "Total", SUM('Renewed'[Complete Count])
  )
```

Comment: Oh ok! That worked perfectly. I'm still learning so I appreciate the help!